# Disable Touch Input Tracking Bubble on 4.4.2 CM 11

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-2

About a week ago my Samsung Note II started tracking all touch input with a bubble. It acts sort of like mouse trails, although there is only one bubble. I don't remember turning this feature on, and after looking through all the settings and applications I can't find any way to disable it. The phone is running a CyanogenMod 11 Nightly (Build cm-11-20140222-NIGHTLY-i605.zip) but I noticed it on previous builds of CM 11 as well.

Here are some screenshots of the bubble tracking touch input in various applications:

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I remembered installing a beta app from Cyanogenmod called [Screencast](http://androidflagship.com/3230-cyanogenmod-screencast-beta-download-google-play-store) which can be used to record the screen if you have a CM 11 ROM. When you start recording there is an option in the notification bar to Show Touches. I had enabled this when playing with the Screencast app, and it continues to track touch input even after you stop the recording. Disabling the Show Touches option fixed my issue.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Go to Setting -> Developer Options -> Show touches -> Off

Comment: Why  downvote(s) against this answer? The answer definitely didn't develop the context around itself but it does the job.